# ASP.NET core occasional 503 response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following setup:

- Framework version: ASP.NET Core 2.1
- Host machine: Amazon Linux
- Run container: derivative of `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime`

My application starts up and runs happily, but occasionally fails health checks by returning `503 Unavailable`. This seems to occur after >= 4 hours of no API requests. No error logs occur on the server, and the web service does not die or restart during that time - subsequent requests are serviced happily with no interruptions in logs.

Interestingly, it seems to occur precisely on the minute of the hours after the application was deployed. For instance, the most recent deploy occurred at 11:08AM, and the `503` occurred at 3:08PM. This has recurred enough times to be very noticeable.

This feels like a JIT caching issue to me (due to lack of restarting and regular intervals of failure), but I can't find any other information about this or others having this problem.

**Question**: Can you explain what is going on, and how I can keep my web application correctly servicing requests even if none occur for several hours?

Comment: I'm more inclined to believe this is a problem in the host than in ASP.NET Core. I've never seen something like this on Windows + IIS

Comment: It looks like the healthcheck is likely hitting a static file - I'm investigating moving that over to an API endpoint and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf if the container's volume mount is configured badly that could be an annoying issue. but in general i would guess healthchecks/liveliness checks should stay away from fs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outcome: after a lot of logging and string-pulling, we determined that the problem was not with the dotnet app at all, but rather higher up in the infrastructure. The bad requests were never reaching the web service at all.